# Error: catch parameter is not a pointer to an interface type iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, exception, xcode4.5

I'm trying to use Exception handling in my Xcode project.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    authenticate = [[UseDb alloc]init];
    @try{
    [authenticate createDatabase];
    }
    @catch (DatabaseCreationException) {
        NSLog(@"failed to create database");
    }
}
```

This is the method where the exception is being thrown:

```
-(void)createDatabase
{

    NSString *docsDir;
    NSArray *dirPaths;
    char *sql_stmt1,*sql_stmt2,*sql_stmt3,*sql_stmt4;
    // Get the documents directory
    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

    // Build the path to the database file
    _mDatabasePathDb = [[NSString alloc]
                     initWithString: [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                                      @"SmartDiaryDatabaseTest2.sqlite"]];

    NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath: _mDatabasePathDb ] == NO)
    {
        const char *dbpath = [_mDatabasePathDb UTF8String];

        if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &_mDb) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            char *errMsg;

            sql_stmt1 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS USERDETAIL (mUserName TEXT PRIMARY KEY, mPassword TEXT,mUname TEXT, mImage TEXT, mGender CHAR, mDob DATE, mEmail TEXT, mAddress TEXT, mMaritalStatus BOOL, mLatitude DOUBLE, mLongitude DOUBLE)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(_mDb, sql_stmt1, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {

            }

            sql_stmt2 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CONTACTS (mName TEXT, mContactno TEXT, mCgender CHAR, mCdob DATE, mCemail TEXT, mClatitude DOUBLE, mClongitude DOUBLE)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(_mDb, sql_stmt2, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"failed to create table");

            }

            sql_stmt3 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TODO (mStartDate DATE, mEndDate DATE, mTaskName TEXT, mTaskDescription TEXT, mPriority INT)";

            if (sqlite3_exec(_mDb, sql_stmt3, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"failed to create table");
            }


            sql_stmt4 = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS FAVORITES (mTdate DATE, mNewsLabel TEXT )";

            if (sqlite3_exec(_mDb, sql_stmt4, NULL, NULL, &errMsg) != SQLITE_OK)
            {

            }
           // sqlite3_close(_mDb);

        } else {
            NSLog(@"failed to create database");
            NSException *e = [DatabaseCreationException exceptionWithName:@"DatabaseCreationFailedException" reason:@"sqlite execution failed" userInfo:nil];
            @throw e;

        }

    }
    sqlite3_close(_mDb);
}
```

I am getting the error mentioned in the question: `catch parameter is not a pointer to an interface type iOS` I'm handling exceptions for the first time in Objective C. Please tell me where I'm going wrong. I have created a new class called DatabaseCreationException and imported it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch exceptions by pointer, like this:

```
@try{
    [authenticate createDatabase];
}
@catch (DatabaseCreationException*ex) {
//                               ^
    NSLog(@"failed to create database");
}
```

Note that Apple strongly recommends against using exceptions for handling run-time situations, reserving them for situations when the application is about to close (i.e. for non-recoverable situations). If the situation is recoverable, Apple recommends using `NSError` ([Exceptions Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Exceptions/Tasks/HandlingExceptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000059-BBCHGJIJ)).

Answer (score 0):

Use a pointer to the exception object:

```
@catch (DatabaseCreationException *e) {
        NSLog(@"failed to create database");
}
```

However I think this approach is wrong anyway; it looks like you are leaking database handles if an exception is thrown. I think you should stick to returning `BOOL` which is more efficient and avoids the leaks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
@try
{
  [authenticate createDatabase];
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{                              
    NSLog(@"Exception: %@", exception);
}
```